Apply groupby aggregate to original table using databricks api (SQL or pyspark)
Found an old question for this problem in pandas:
I want to do something that seems pretty easy in a spreadsheet but I can't figure the syntax in pandas. I have a data set that can be grouped. I want to determine the aggregate stats for each of the groups, but then use the aggregates to create a new column back in the original data frame.
For example, if my data frame looks like this:
d = pandas.dataframe({'class', : ['f1', 'f2', 'f3', 'f1'], 
'user': ['jack', 'jen', 'joe', 'jan'], 
'screen': [12, 23, 13, 15] }) 

Original accepted solution:
d['gp'] = d.groupby('class')['screen'].transform('std')
print (d)
  class  screen  user       gp
0    f1      12  jack  2.12132
1    f2      23   jen      NaN
2    f3      13   joe      NaN
3    f1      15   jan  2.12132

My question is how would we achieve the result using databricks api (SQL or pysaprk) only

from pyspark.sql.functions import stddev

data = [('f1', 'jack', 12),
        ('f2', 'jen', 23),
        ('f3', 'joe', 13),
        ('f1', 'jan', 15)]

cols = ['class', 'user', 'screen']
df = spark.createDataFrame(data, cols)

agg_stats = df.groupby('class').agg(stddev('screen').alias('gp'))
result_df = df.join(agg_stats, on='class', how='left')
result_df.show()

+-----+----+------+------------------+
|class|user|screen|                gp|
+-----+----+------+------------------+
|   f1|jack|    12|2.1213203435596424|
|   f2| jen|    23|              NULL|
|   f3| joe|    13|              NULL|
|   f1| jan|    15|2.1213203435596424|
+-----+----+------+------------------+

